# Simplify Trig Identity in Sinθ and/or Cosθ

Tags: trigonometry

I just need to simplify in terms of $\sin θ$ and/or $\cos θ$.

I did this one earlier today but forgot how I did it. I just need help on the other two.

$\dfrac{\cosθ}{\sinθ} + \dfrac{1}{\cosθ}$ = $\dfrac{\cos^2θ +\sinθ}{\sinθ \cosθ}$

Question 1: $\sinθ +  \dfrac{1}{\cosθ}$

Question 2: $\dfrac{\sinθ}{\cosθ} + \dfrac{1}{\sinθ}$

Comment: You have posted an answer which is nearly identical in content to this one, deleted it, and then reposted it. Can you explain why you did this?

Comment: @TobyMak No idea. I'm just asking for some help here.

Comment: Hi Skim and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Moreover, I don't understand your questions: what is the relationship between the identity above and the questions 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have $$\sin(x)+\frac{1}{\cos(x)}=\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)+1}{\cos(x)}$$
and $$\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}+\frac{1}{\sin(x)}=\frac{\sin^2(x)+\cos(x)}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}$$